# How to drive an HDTV with an 8 bit MPU?

Tags: signal, computer-architecture, hdmi

Is it possible/reasonable to generate a 480 x 270 image with an 8 bit MPU, store the image in external memory, upscale the image to 1920 x 1080, and generate an HDMI signal for the upscaled image? Also, is there an IC that can just take an image, upscale the image, and then generate an HDMI signal? Or does the image have to be upscaled beforehand and passed to an IC that can generate an HDMI signal?

Comment: Too broad a question. Possible? yes. Reasonable? Probably not. We don't have any idea what upscaling artefacts you can tolerate, or how long your 8 bit MPU has to do the task, for a start.

Comment: Yes, there are ICs like the [TDA9984](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/TDA9984A.pdf) that can do the upscaling for you, but you'd need to convert your image into a standard video signal first. Or you could use something like the Raspberry Pi to read the image and upscale it in software to drive the HDMI output. It's no small amount of CPU power you'd need though.

Comment: Tempted to say "no" - by far the easiest and cheapest way of doing this is to throw the 8 bit MPU away and use a 32-bit one that has HDMI output.